# UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.GestureRecognizer works in Editor but not able to build

Tags: unity-game-engine

Running my application in Editor works fine, but when I try to build I get following Error: error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Input' does not exist in the namespace`UnityEngine.XR.WSA'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Does anyone had an similar issue?

Comment: What is your target device? And which Unity Version are you using?

Comment: windows standalone. I tied with 19.1, 18.2, 17.2 and 17.4 LTS